# I want to redirect example.com/chapter-foo.php to example.com/chapter.php

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a site with some pages like that:

- example.com/dogs-foo1.php
- example.com/dogs-foo2.php
- example.com/dogs-foo3.php

And then

- example.com/cats-foo1.php
- example.com/cats-foo2.php
- example.com/cats-foo3.php

Now I have simplified the site with tab menus and I only have

- example.com/dogs.php
- example.com/cats.php

Now I want the people who try to go to: example.com/cats-foo1.php
be redirected to: example.com/cats.php
instead of getting a 404
Is there anyway, maybe with htaccess?

Comment: Certainly that is possible, you want to implement rewriting rules. But SO is not a free code writing service. We are here to help you with your own code, we are not here to do your work for you. For that please hire a (payed) programmer.

Comment: You are expected to attempt to solve your task yourself. So get started, read into the topic, there are lots of easy to follow tutorials. Also here on SO there are roughly 658395475 answered questions you can take a look at that deal with exactly the topic you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?cats-.+.php$ /cats.php [R=301]
```

For this to work you will need to enable the rewriting module into your http server. You should place it in the http servers host configuration. If you decide to use a dynamic configuration files instead (`.htaccess`) you need to enable their interpretation first (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the official documentation).

---

I would recommend however to go a step further and use URLs along the pattern `https://example.com/cats`, so without the trailing `.php` as is the standard these days. You need some additional internal rewrite rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# external redirect from /cats-foo.php to /cats
RewriteRule ^/?cats-.+\.php$ /cats [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?cats\.php$ /cats [R=301]
# internal rewrite 
RewriteRule ^/?cat$ /cats.php [END]
```

This again can be generalized:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# external redirect from /cats-foo.php to /cats
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+])-.+.php$ /$1 [R=301]
# internal rewrite 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+])$ /$1.php [END]
```

If you experience a http status 500 with that rule in place chances are you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will find entries in your http servers error log files complaining about the `END` flag. In that case replace it with the `L` flag and try again.

You probably will have to adjust those line, we don't know your specific situation. But the above should get you started *along with reading the documentation of the tools you use*, which you can start here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).